# Create an Azure Bot for Instagram Messenger

Tags: facebook, botframework, instagram, instagram-api

I need to create an Azure Bot connected to Instagram Messenger for being able to connect to Microsoft Dynamics OmniChannel.

The Facebook Messenger is already a native channel in Azure Bot and the Instagram Messenger API seems more or less identical to its Facebook counterpart.
Therefore I was asking myself whether you could use the Facebook Messenger channel for connecting to Instagram Messenger as well?

If not, which would be the best way to connecting to Instagram Messenger?

Answer (score 0):

The BotFramework service only supports specific channels. Anything outside of those channels requires a custom adapter to be constructed to facilitate communication between the bot and the unsupported service. This is typically done by building a custom adapter. There are examples in the [botbuilder-community](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity) repos that you can use to help design yours. Both the [dotnet](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries) and [JS](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-js/tree/master/libraries) libraries contains several adapters that you can reference.